# Volume of nitrogen gas produced during taking off

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry, gas-laws

> The fuel in the buster rockets of the Space Shuttle is constituted of a mixture of ammonium perchlorate, $\ce{NH4ClO4}$, and aluminum powder. One of the reactions taking place during taking off is given by
>   $$\ce{6 NH4ClO4(s) + 10 Al(s) -> 5 Al2O3(s) + 3 N2(g) + 6 HCl(g) + 9 H2O(g)}$$
>   The indication (s) and (g) signify solid and gaseous phase. Suppose that these rockets are loaded with $\pu{11.75 ton}$ of ammonium perchlorate and $\pu{2.70 ton}$ of aluminum.
>
> Calculate the volume of nitrogen gas produced during taking off under normal
>   conditions ($\pu{0^\circ C}$ and atmospheric pressure, so that $\pu{1 mol}$ corresponds to $\pu{22.4 L}$ of gas).

I got to the point where it's $\pu{10^5 mol}$ for each of the compounds.
How do you get to the answer $\pu{6.72e5 L}$?

Comment: LOL - Had to run through calculations twice. I used English tons rather than metric tons.

Comment: I ran right over this reading the problem statement but the statement *(0 ∘C and atmospheric pressure, so that 1 L corresponds to 22.4 mol of gas).* is backwards. 1 mole of gas is 22.4 liters.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/80780/what-volume-does-one-mole-of-an-ideal-gas-occupy

Comment: @MaxW I have no idea how I missed it. Those sneaky 22.4 *liters*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your next step is to identify the **limiting reagent**.

Observe that six moles of ammonium perchlorate react with ten moles of aluminum.  So by taking ratios you find that:

1)  The $10^5$ moles of ammonium perchlorate you started with react with approximately $1.7×10^5$ moles of aluminum.

2)  The $10^5$ moles of aluminum you started with react with $6×10^4$ moles of ammonium perchlorate.

Now there is a problem with (1) -- you have only $1.0×10^5$ moles of aluminum available so not all of the ammonium perchlorate can react as indicated in (1).  So we now look at (2) -- it indicates that all of the aluminum can react and you still have $4×10^4$ moles of ammonium perchlorate remaining.

Thus we can realize condition (2) rather than (1) because the amount of reaction is limited by the aluminum you have available.  Thus **aluminum is the limiting reagent**.

Now that you know the limiting reagent you can infer how much product is formed.  With $10^5$ moles of aluminum all being consumed, you should be able to see that $3×10^4$ moles of nitrogen molecules are formed as gas.  The volume under normal conditions should then follow.