Why is the volume of one mole of gas 22.4 or 22.7 dm3?
I can’t figure out why one mole of any gases’ volume is 22.4 or 22.7 dm3. From my research the most reliable answer has to do with the ideal gas law. I think it can be used to interpret the reason.
But while trying to calculate the volume of one mole of any gas it was hard for me to find out why the constant R, ideal gas constant, can be defined in terms of the volume of gas, which we want to figure it out using this equation. In other words, I think we can’t define the volume of gases by a formula that has a constant value, where this constant can also be defined in this formula by using the volume of gases.

PV = nRT - sure, R is the universal gas constant, but primarily is a conversion from temperature units (T) to energy units (J). And, yes, the value of R can be measured using a variety of near-ideal gases and varying P, V, n, and/or T as desired. I'm not sure where the constant value you are struggling with comes in here.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/101559/why-do-different-gases-have-the-same-molar-volume

It is probably related to the old standard pressure 101325 Pa (22.4 dm3/mol) and new one 100000 Pa ( 22.7 dm3/mol).

Not sure if this helps your understanding,  but see kinetic theory of gases, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory_of_gases, for theory of gas molecules acting as particles. Note  PV derivation.

In the past units of atmosphere were used 1 atm $\equiv$ 101325 Pa as Poutnik comments. In SI units we use $10^5$ Pa which give slightly different answers. Either is correct depending on the set of units you use.

I edited your post for clarity. If you disaprove of the edits these can be rolled back, but please note that as written the question was a tad confusing.

The atmosphere unit $\pu{1 atm}$ is defined as $\pu{1 atm} = \pu{101 325 Pa}$, originally based on the hydrostatic pressure of $\pu{760 mm Hg}$ and later redefined. In the old good times, this was taken as the standard pressure: $p^{\circ} = \pu{1 atm}$.
Later, SI standardization and IUPAC Goldbook recommendation  modified the definition of the standard pressure in 1982 as $p^{\circ} = \pu{100 000 Pa}$.
But the old habits die hard and especially older sources use the older  definition of the standard pressure. Different standard pressures inevitably lead to different molar volumes of ideal gases.
$$V_\text{m, old} = \dfrac{RT^{\circ}}{p^{\circ}_\text{old}} \approx \dfrac{(\pu{8.31446 J K-1 mol-1})(\pu{293.15 K})}{\pu{101325 Pa}} \approx \pu{22.4E-3 m3 mol-1}$$ $$V_\text{m, current} \approx \dfrac{RT^{\circ}}{p^{\circ}} \approx \dfrac{(\pu{8.31446 J K-1 mol-1})(\pu{293.15 K})}{\pu{100000 Pa}} \approx \pu{22.7E-3 m3 mol-1}$$

Taking a cue from the other answer: do not conflate R and the molar volume ($V_\mathrm{m}$).
R is a linear proportionality constant between p, V, T and n and can be expressed in a variety of units, for instance energy per unit temperature and amount of substance ($\pu{8.31446261815324JK^{−1}mol^{−1}}$). It will assume different units and values depending on for instance whether the pressure is expressed in units of atmosphere ($\pu{atm}$) or pascal ($\pu{Pa}$); temperature in degrees Kelvin or Rankine; or volume in pints or litres.
The linear proportionality is applicable to any gas that behaves ideally which means n and T are linearly proportional to p and V, that is, $$\frac{pV}{nT} = \mathrm{constant} =\mathrm{R}$$
The above can also be written as
$$V_\mathrm{m} = \frac{nT}{p} \mathrm{R}$$
where $V_\mathrm{m}$ is the volume of one mole of gas. For a given temperature and pressure $V_\mathrm{m}$ is therefore also a constant.
You might want to reflect on why you can relate these variables in one ideal equation of state. Both pressure and temperature are measures of the energy content of a gas, whereas n and V are measures of the amount of gas. When you divide n by V (to compute density) or V by n (to compute molar volume) you lose information about the size of the system (its extensive nature).
Note that engineers might use a modified form that relates the mass density (or its inverse, the specific volume), pressure and temperature. Volume does not appear explicitly in this form of the equation.
Look up also Boyle's law, Charles' law etc. If you don't have an ideal gas you need a different equation of state.

First of all, the value of molar volume at STP(Standard Temperature and Pressure) and NTP(Normal Temperature and Pressure) is 22.7 L/mol and 22.4 L/mol respectively.
This is because molar volume($V^*$) is defined as total volume divided by total mass.
$$
        V^* = \frac{RT}{P}
$$
where $V^*$ = molar volume,
$R$ = universal gas constant,
$T$ = temperature,
$P$ = Pressure
Now the conditions for NTP are as follows:-
$T$ = 273 K,
$P$ = 1 atm = 101.325 kPa
And for STP:-
$T$ = 273 K,
$P$ = 1 bar = 100 kPa
Put the above values in the equation for molar volume mentioned above and check out the results yourself.
