# Volume of dried gas at STP

Tags: gas-laws, pressure, vapor-pressure

> A $54.0\ \mathrm{mL}$ sample of oxygen is collected over water at $20\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ and $770\ \mathrm{Torr}$ pressure. What is the volume of the dry gas at STP?

By using the combined gas law, I came up with the answer $\pu{51.2 mL}$.

$770 - 21.1 = 748.9\ \mathrm{Torr}$ pressure for oxygen

$21.1$ = vapor pressure of water at $23\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$

$\frac{P_1V_1}{ T_1 }= \frac{P_2V_2 }{ T_2}$

$\frac{748.9V_1}{273 }= \frac{770\times54}{296}$

$V_1 = \pu{51.2 mL}$

Is this how it's supposed to be done?

Comment: No. What are the conditions for STP?

Comment: @MaxW ohh I see now. STP would be 760 torr and 273 K so P1 should be 760 and P2 should be 748.9. Would that be right?

Comment: That is correct. However I'll point out that [STP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_conditions_for_temperature_and_pressure) is a bit different now than 760 mm Hg and O C. It is now about 750 mm Hg at 0 C.

Comment: So $$\frac{P_{STP}V_{STP}}{T_{STP}} = \frac{PV}{T}$$

Comment: I like your comment about not closing it MaxW, but my own comment is why don't you put your answer in the answer section :P

Comment: @user75030 see [this post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/80780/41556) for details on how the definition of STP has changed.

Comment: @CharlieCrown - I wasn't trying to answer the question per se but rather I was trying to lead the OP to the answer.